# Why chrome shows alert randomly when try to open custom protocol url with location.href?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, web-applications, compatibility, custom-protocol

i had took a look to another threads about chrome and custom protocol apps, but i couldn't resolve a doubt i've got. In my web app, when you click a button it fire a new tab with an webpage (window.open(url, "_blank")). The new tab is opened with the url (annother web app with https protocol). This url fire a javascript function on load that verifies some things and then generate a custom url, for example myurl://base64code, and put it in an existing iframe in this way windows.frames['myframe'].location.href=theCustomProtocolUrl. i tried in different ways (location.replace, create a new iframe and set the url, etc) and i always have the same problem. If i refresh (ctrl f5) the page it always show the dialog or if i open the link with the developer console opened. But if i click my button and the page is opened in a new tab it doesn't work only if i refresh (ctrl+f5). This works perfectly on IE11, it launch the app directly.

Any ideas why chrome, and edge, works like this?

UPDATE: I have found the reason, is i use the protocolcheck.js (https://gist.github.com/vladimirtsyupko/cfcd332476b16683bb0b) library.

First i tried to open a protocol with the timeoutHack (it use blur event) and then, after failing, it fires the other url (in this case https) and the dialog doensn't appear. I found a bug with blur event on chrome > 85 https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1137801

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.